# How can i make strtotime go to the beginning of a day

Tags: php, strtotime

I have an issue in my code whereby i sometimes need to add 1 day, 2 days or sometimes even 3 days onto the current day.

I'm using

```
$today = strtotime('today');
```

then based of holidays, weekends and other parameters i may need to add days / weekdays like so

```
$date = strtotime('+2 weekdays', $today);
```

or

```
$date = strtotime('+2 days', $today);
```

However, this seems to add 24 hours onto the current time when what i need ideally is the first second of the day. Unfortunately i cannot change the today timestamp because if it is current day then its time critical, but when adding days it needs to be the first second of the new day.

Any help or understanding on this issue i personally have would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract from result timestamp value `$timestamp % (24*3600)`;
Example:

```
$timestamp = mt_rand(1500000000, 1600000000); 
$timestamp -= $timestamp % (24*3600);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

P.S. But better to use `DateTime` class. There is method `setTime()`:

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime->modify('+2 day');
$datetime->setTime(0, 0, 0, 0);
$timestamp = $datetime->getTimestamp();
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

Comment: Thanks for the duo answer. All sorted now

Answer (score 3):

You can use a date/time formatted string as input to `strtotime` to specify the time you want. If you add that as the second parameter to `strtotime` that can get you the time you want.

```php
$date = strtotime('+2 weekdays', strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $today));
```

There are easier options though. You can also just ask `strtotime` for midnight.

```php
$date = strtotime('midnight +2 weekdays');
```

or a specific time.

```php
$date = strtotime('01:23 +2 weekdays');
```

https://strtotime.co.uk/ is a useful site for testing out the capabilities of `strtotime`

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(new DateInterval('P"your needed days"D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
eg:'P2D'
OUTPUT:::2019-01-27
```

in this 'P' specifies the period in the date and then you can add year(Y),month(M)and day(D) and then for time, need to specify time(T) then hour(H),min(i or M) and sec(S).
refer below http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php